# Docker node gets down after promoted from worker to manager

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Docker swarm consists of 3 nodes:

```
ID                            HOSTNAME          STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
ec9gxe01ofk38xb3o6hg8xccv     docker-worker01   Ready     Active                          20.10.9
e9eoqfjqgfoj5i7bp83dqoyn6     docker-worker02   Ready     Active                          20.10.9
nbvdgqwbw03m7huj0cscw7whc *   server03          Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.9
```

When I try to promote worker node in manager node, it ends with "Down" status:

```
[root@server03 ~]# docker node promote docker-worker02
Node docker-worker02 promoted to a manager in the swarm.
[root@server03 ~]# docker node  ls
ID                            HOSTNAME          STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
ec9gxe01ofk38xb3o6hg8xccv     docker-worker01   Ready     Active                          20.10.9
e9eoqfjqgfoj5i7bp83dqoyn6     docker-worker02   Down      Active                          20.10.9
nbvdgqwbw03m7huj0cscw7whc *   server03          Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.9
```

Could not find any logs showing an error on note server though.

Answer (score 0):

I had to make that Down node leave and re-join the swarm. That helped the status back to Ready.

ie:

from docker-worker02,

`docker swarm leave`

then

`swarm join --token <token> <ip:port>`